# How can I disable npm run build errors?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I currently have an interesting error with npm run build and I don't know what's wrong. Is there a way to run the build with errors?

````
$ npm run build

> todoo@0.1.0 build D:\FitnessTracker
> tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todoo@0.1.0 build: `tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todoo@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\raul.gimcojocaru\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-11T13_25_39_104Z-debug.log```
````

Answer (score 0):

That project seems to expect an UNIX-style shell and you're on Windows.

You could try replacing the `build` script entry with just

`"build": "tsc"`

but there's no guarantees things will still work.

Comment: I tried it right now but it doesn't do anything. It doesn't log anything. It runs and then nothing.                                                      
```npm run build

> todoo@0.1.0 build D:\FitnessTracker
> tsc```

Comment: Tsc might not output anything if it's successful.

Comment: I found the issue. It shouldn't be tsc there, it should be react-scripts build. I solved the problem.